# Upgrade Dockerfile for Quarkus 1.11->1.13

Tags: docker, dockerfile, quarkus

I'm trying to upgrade our Quarkus version from 1.11 to 1.13 and I can't figure out how to update my `Dockerfile`. Below is what I had for 1.11 and what I tried for 1.13 (unsuccessfully), with the error I get. Any help would be appreciated.

Working Dockerfile for 1.11:

```
COPY --from=build /opt/work/java/modules/my-service/.build/ /opt/${SERVICE}/
COPY --from=build /opt/work/java/modulesmy-service/.build/my-service*-runner.jar /opt/my-service/
...
CMD eval JAVA_OPTS=\"$JAVA_OPTS\" && java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /opt/my-service/my-service*-runner.jar
```

Attempted change for 1.13:

```
COPY --from=build /opt/work/java/modules/my-service/.build/quarkus-app/* /opt/my-service/
...
CMD eval JAVA_OPTS=\"$JAVA_OPTS\" && java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /opt/my-service/quarkus-run.jar
```

Error deploying:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change is because of the switch to the fast-jar as the default package. See [this](https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-1-12-0-final-released/#fast-jar-as-default) for details.

To build a docker container for the new packaging type, you essentially need to do something like:

```
COPY target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/
```

as can be seen [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/getting-started/src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm#L45-L49).

Comment: I'm already copying the app files in with: `COPY --from=build /opt/work/java/modules/my-service/.build/quarkus-app/* /opt/my-service/`

My error is occurring on the `CMD` step. In your example, I don't understand where `/deployments/run-java.sh` is coming from. I don't see it in the `quarkus-app` directory that's generated from the `quarkusBuild` task.

Comment: `run-java.sh` in my example comes from the base image.

Comment: I propose you take a look at image created by my example and yours with `dive`, that should reveal what your example is missing on the container image's file system

Comment: I might just use `quarkus.package.type=legacy-jar` for now until I can figure this out (just noticed this in your first link).

Comment: I figured it out, my `COPY` didn't work as I expected. When i split it up into 4 lines like you have it fixed it.

Comment: Cool! Mind accepting the answer so future readers know it works? Thanks